# Send form data to controller

Tags: dataflow

I want to send from data to my controller function from phtml file but I'm not sure how to catch sent data in variables in my controller.
phtml code is like

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/pharmacist/orderapprove'); ?>">
  <table style="width:50%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Qty Dispensed</th>
            <th>Cost / Unit</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Current Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($ordered_items as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item->getName() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered() + 0?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo round($item->getPrice(),2) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo round($item->getRowTotal(),2) ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php 
             $itemStatus = $item->getApprovalStatus();
        // Load the option text
        $itemOptionText = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
                                ->getAttribute('approval_status')
                                ->getSource()->getOptionText($itemStatus);
        echo ($itemOptionText);
             ?>
            </td>
            <td id="status-<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
            <button data-item_id type="button" id="approve-<?php echo $item->getId();?>" value="Approved" onclick="saveApprovalStatus('<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>', 'Approved');">Approve</button>

            <button type="button" id="reject-<?php echo $item->getId();?>" value="Rejected" onclick="saveApprovalStatus('<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>', 'Rejected');">Reject</button>
           <div style="display:none" id="item-status-<?php echo $item->getId();?>"></div>
           </td>
           <td>
                 <textarea id='comment-<?php echo $item->getId();?>' placeholder="Give reason for rejection"  name='comment' value="abc"></textarea>

           </td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="order-approve" value="Approve"></button>
    <input type="submit" id="order-reject" value="Reject"></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller function

```
public function orderapproveAction()
{

          $orderItemId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_item_id');
          $approvalStatus = $this->getRequest()->getPost('approval_status');
          $approvalDescription = $this->getRequest()->getPost('approval_description');
            echo ($approvalStatus );
            echo ($approvalDescription );   
        exit();
    }
```

But these values are not echoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't give names to your inputs,  the request won't find your data if you don't identify the inputs with a name
Example:

```
<input type ="text" id="approval-status" name="approval _ status" />
```

Comment: I've just given name in  `<textarea id='comment-<?php echo $item->getId();?>' placeholder="Give reason for rejection"  name='comment'></textarea>` and in controller function   `$approvalDescription = $this->getRequest()->getPost('comment');echo ($approvalDescription);` .Still it's not echoing.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around the variable off your echo statement

Answer (score 0):

order_item_id , approval_status & approval_description are not specified anywhere inside the form. Use name tags if they are form fields. Is any other form being submitted to same controller?

Comment: No, only one form is being submitted to that controller.

Comment: Sorry I dont have a development environment right now. Try deleting the semicolon inside

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/pharmacist/orderapprove'); ?>">

and see what happens

Comment: It is hitting my controller function still I'm not able to see any output.

Comment: Anyway edit your question code to reflect the new names you gave so that other people see that too